# Is it possible to set a fixed ImageView to center of map and display the LatLng

Tags: android, google-maps

The question is obvious.. We can set a fixed ImageView on map but how about to take the LatLng while panning the map? Is that possible to make ImageView to behave like a marker? Any ideas?

Comment: "The question is obvious" -- to you, perhaps. "Is that possible to make ImageView to behave like a marker?" -- why not use a marker, since it already behaves like a marker?

Comment: Because when I move the map marker got lost , but when I use ImageView at center it got fixed on the screen and when I move the map It do not lost anymore.. With marker we can get latlng values and display it when I use with onMarkerDragEnd() function in your book .. So is it possible to implement something like that when panning the map stopped, the current position of ImageView on the map retrieves me the latlng values..

Comment: having same problem have you fixed your problem?

Comment: just add the ImageView and handle maps onCameraChangeListener.. It will keep ImageView fixed .. This would do the trick mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener()

Answer (score 0):

You know where the `ImageView` is, because you put it on the screen. You can find out its pixel coordinates using methods that are inherited from `View`, [perhaps `getDrawingRect()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingRect%28android.graphics.Rect%29).

You can then [use a `Projection`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection) to convert pixel coordinates to latitude and longitude.

Comment: hmm it has the logic but hard for a newbie like me .. Is there any implemented examples that I can test or similar to it .. thanks anyway